# How to handle a GUI string with "±" in Qt source code?

Tags: c++, qt

When I use "±" in my GUI sources, my Qt-5.6.2 does not like it and the GUI of the program just displays it a black rhomb. How do I have to code that in the right way? It seems it's not in the common latin set.

Comment: Save source file as unicode? UTF-8 for example?

Comment: @RvdK: that is always a big mess with all the editors. For instance a SVN unified diff with using Notepad++ as editor shows "Â±"

Comment: Recommended reading: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign#Encodings):

```
QString s(0x00B1);
qDebug() << s;
```

In the above code, `QString(QChar)` constructor is implicitly used (a QChar is instantiated out of a 16 bit integer literal in hexadecimal notation).

About *ui* files: the `uic` tool will turn non ASCII characters found in string literals into [octal escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). In a generated header, one can find a line like this (inside the `retranslateUi` method):

```
pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "\302\261", Q_NULLPTR));
```

The second argument passed to `QApplication::translate` is the 2 bytes long UTF-8 representation of the plus-minus sign.

Comment: And I also have found an entry <string>±</string> in the .ui file. Is that OK or do I also have to use a trick for those ones?

Comment: Anyway, it does look right in the GUI, so I guess it's not a problem to have it in .ui files :-D  (it was a prefix property of a spinbox here)